# Can Linq-to-SQL-generated entities be moved outside the data context?

Tags: linq-to-sql, mapping, dto, entities

We need to map L2S entities to DTOs, and vice versa. Right now, our L2S entities are in a Data project, and our domain (dto) entities are in an Entities project.Performing a mapping is difficult without creating a circular reference. If both sets of entities lived in the same project, the entities could map themselves to each other (L2S to DTO and vice versa).

Is there a way to move the L2S entities, but leave the data context in the Data project? Or is there just a better solution to this, in general?

Comment: you can build the translation/mapping business logic in 3-rd project that reference both of those, there is no need for either of your entities to be aware of each other

Comment: But it's not a simple foo-foo mapping. If we have a list of animals, and some are dogs and some are cats, what do you call to do the conversion? Calling a method that maps a type directly to its DTO counterpart would work that way, but when you don't know the type at design time, you need to let the proper subclass do the work.

Comment: use reflection, if you can, otherwise it will be hell to manage long term; the scenario you are describing sounds like horrible design

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking how to make the current implementation work. I'm looking for the right solution overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what K Ivanov was suggesting is probably the easiest way to handle this; keep the L2S and DTO classes (blissfully) unaware of each other, and have a third, central place where the mapping in either direction goes.

I would also ask, with a tiny bit of a wince in case of backlash, but if keeping the projects separate is truly serving a purpose... or just making things more complex.

Comment: With what you're suggesting, what would the call, to do the conversion, look like?

Comment: Probably just a simple method call on a mapper class that takes a ref of one and returns an equivalent ref of the other. Instead of a mapper class, it could be in a repository class for the L2S objects. That way it could also directly handle cases where it needs to create new instances, instead of needing to delegate to a repository/service class separately. Depends on what your architecture would be, otherwise.